# How to express the reasoning for Weka instance classification?

Tags: java, machine-learning, tree, artificial-intelligence, weka

**Background:**

If I open Weka Explorer GUI, train a J48 tree and test using the NSL-KDD training and testing datasets a pruned tree would be produced. Weka Explorer GUI expresses the algorithms reasoning for stating whether something would be classified as an anomaly or not in terms of queries such as *src_bytes <= 28*.

[Screenshot of Weka Explorer GUI showing pruned tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwOy.png)

**Question:**

Referring to the pruned tree example produced by the Weka Explorer GUI, how can I programmatically have weka express the reasoning for each instance classification in Java?

> i.e. Instance A was classified as an anomaly as *src_bytes* < 28 &&
>   dst_host_srv_count < 88 && dst_bytes < 3 etc.

**So Far I've been able to:**

- Train and test a J48 tree on the NSL-KDD dataset.
- Output a description of the J48 tree within Java.
- Return the J48 tree as an if-then statement.

**But** I simply have no idea how whilst iterating through each instance during the testing phase, to express the reasoning for each classification; without each time manually outputting the J48 tree as an if-then statement and adding numerous println expressing when each was triggered (which I'd really rather not do, as this would dramatically increase the human intervention requirements in the long-term).

**Additional Screenshots:**

[Screenshot of the 'description of the J48 tree within Java'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBHkb.png)

[Screenshot of the 'J48 tree as an if-then statement'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhXfB.png)

**Code:**

```
    public class Junction_Tree {

    String train_path = "KDDTrain+.arff";
    String test_path = "KDDTest+.arff";
    double accuracy;
    double recall;
    double precision;
    int correctPredictions;
    int incorrectPredictions;
    int numAnomaliesDetected;
    int numNetworkRecords;

    public void run() {
        try {
            Instances train = DataSource.read(train_path);
            Instances test = DataSource.read(test_path);
            train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
            test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);

            if (!train.equalHeaders(test))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("datasets are not compatible..");

            Remove rm = new Remove();
            rm.setAttributeIndices("1");

            J48 j48 = new J48();
            j48.setUnpruned(true);

            FilteredClassifier fc = new FilteredClassifier();
            fc.setFilter(rm);
            fc.setClassifier(j48);

            fc.buildClassifier(train);

            numAnomaliesDetected = 0;
            numNetworkRecords = 0;
            int n_ana_p = 0;
            int ana_p = 0;
            correctPredictions = 0;
            incorrectPredictions = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
                double pred = fc.classifyInstance(test.instance(i));
                String a = "anomaly";
                String actual;
                String predicted;
                actual = test.classAttribute().value((int) test.instance(i).classValue());
                predicted = test.classAttribute().value((int) pred);

                if (actual.equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                    numAnomaliesDetected++;
                if (actual.equalsIgnoreCase(predicted))
                    correctPredictions++;
                if (!actual.equalsIgnoreCase(predicted))
                    incorrectPredictions++;
                if (actual.equalsIgnoreCase(a) && predicted.equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                    ana_p++;
                if ((!actual.equalsIgnoreCase(a)) && predicted.equalsIgnoreCase(a))
                    n_ana_p++;
                numNetworkRecords++;
            }
            accuracy = (correctPredictions * 100) / (correctPredictions + incorrectPredictions);
            recall = ana_p * 100 / (numAnomaliesDetected);
            precision = ana_p * 100 / (ana_p + n_ana_p);

            System.out.println("\n\naccuracy: " + accuracy + ", Correct Predictions: " + correctPredictions
                    + ", Incorrect Predictions: " + incorrectPredictions);

        writeFile(j48.toSource(J48_if-then.java));

        writeFile(j48.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Junction_Tree JT1 = new Junction_Tree();
        JT1.run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it myself, but according to the [WEKA documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html#getMembershipValues-weka.core.Instance-) the `J48` class includes a `getMembershipValues` method. This method should return an array that indicates the node membership of an instance. One of the few mentions of this method appears to be in [this](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/SOLVED-j48-tree-display-number-of-instances-and-errors-in-leaves-for-test-set-instead-of-training-set-td37617.html) thread on the WEKA forums.

Other than this, I can't find any information on possible alternatives other than the one you mentioned.